# Heroku Django website relation does not exist on PostgreSql Database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I developped a website which runs fine on my local machine.
I uploaded my site and the Postgres database to Heroku. It displayed correctly, and I'm able to access to the admin console. In the front page of my site I have links that make request to my database, but I receive "relation "mytable" does not exist"

I'm able to make request manually with heroku pg:psql without any problems.

My models are like this :

```
class Data(models.Model):
i = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
version = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
id = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
attributes = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
audiofiles = models.JSONField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'data'
```

On my settings.py I have the following for Database node (I replaced infos for obvious reasons):

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'dbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'dbpassword',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=card'
        }
    }
}

db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Here my requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.3.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.1.7
django-heroku==0.3.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
psycopg2==2.8.6
pytz==2021.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
whitenoise==5.2.0
```

I tryed many things like :

- heroku run python manage.py makemigrations followed by migrate
- heroku run python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
- Drop my database a recreate it
- makemigrations on local then commit the change to heroku (and migrate again on heroku)

If I connect to heroku pg:psql, I can make requests just like my app did, for example `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE i = 1250;`

Finally, I guess all prerequisites for heroku are satisfied, because I'm able to upload my site, and its welcome page is displayed properly.

Thousands of thanks if someone can help me :)